# Cannot connect to Sql Server from Visual Studio (in the process of creating a new Entity Data Model): login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: entity-framework-6, database-connection, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016

I know there are similar questions, but I have a specific problem.

`Microsoft Visual Studio (2017)` pops up this error when I try to create a DB connection for my `Entity Data Model`

> The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following
>   information: Login failed for user 'sa'.

[image]

What I've already checked:

1) The `sa` user's password **hasn't expired** or **isn't different** than what I have specified.

2) The `sa` user **has not been disabled**, either by being denied permission to connect to the database engine nor having the login disabled.

3) My instance of `SQL Server 2016 (Developer Edition)` **is configured** for `SQL authentication`.

4) **SQL Server is running** and I also can connect to it by `SQL Server Management Studio (v17.1)` via `sa` and `Windows Authentication` as well.

---

What the problem could be?

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried to create a DB connection, when adding `ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> EF Designer from database -> New Connection -> Microsoft SQL Server Database File` (the SchoolDB.mdf wasn't attached to SQL Server... maybe this is the source of the problem)

Comment: Something doesn't sit right here. You are connecting to a database file in your projects folder? Are you sure it's the same database file being used by SQL Server?

Comment: @JacobH thanks for your hint. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I tried to **carry out the same action** (make a connection to database (`SchoolDB.mdf`) and attach the `SchoolDB.mdf` file to SQL Server), and then  Visual Studio gave me a hint:

> The database file that you are attempting to connect is not compatible
>   with the current instance of SQL Server.

[image]

Then VS suggested me to **upgrade the database file** (`SchoolDB.mdf`).

[image]

After I'd done an **upgrade of the *.mdf** file (that I was trying to attach to SQL Server and make a connection to this DB after that), I **could establish a connection to this database** (already **attached** to SQL Server).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRD04.png)

PS: I found out that `SchoolDB.mdf` was created by `SQL Server 2012`, while I tried to connect it to `SQL Server 2016`.